# Dynamic External Content Type

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I want to pass a parameter to an external content type based on which it selects the records to display on the sharepoint list.
 Eg: I pass a parameter customer name and the external content type loads the data as select * from  where customer name=. 
Is this possible.. If not, can anyone suggest a way to acheive this using share point designer 2010.

Any suggestions would be of great help.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible if you write your own CRUD operations.  I have a enum table which I have to write a stored procedure for each of the operation and I get full control of on the input and return.  Be sure to add a return identifier on the CREATE operation.